# Can I use Cube Analog 29" as touring bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, touring, travelling

*I don't know if there is an excellent place for asking this kind of questions or not, but please help me, I need professional people's help.*

I know many people who ride their mountain bicycles as a touring bicycle. And the touring bikes are usually more expensive, and I'm going to travel using [Cube Analog](http://www.cube.eu/en/products/mtb-hardtail/analog/cube-analog-greynblue-2016/).
[image]

---

**What do you think?**

Can I screw (install) rack, carrier, fender, luggage and something else on [Cube Analog](http://www.cube.eu/en/products/mtb-hardtail/analog/cube-analog-greynblue-2016/)?

---

### UPDATE

I made my bicycle trip, and used Analog.
That is an excellent bicycle, and I had no problem with that. But I think it is better to have a touring bike, that should be more comfortable. Something like Cube Central *That should be a little more expensive :)*

Comment: Looks like a pretty nice bike, but I doubt you'd need that suspension fork for road touring.  I'd sure check out a regular chromoly steel front fork, with lugs for mounting rack up front.   Some folks like drop handlebars for touring because it gives you more options for where to put your hands on a long ride.

Comment: Yes I agree, it's pretty nice and looks professional as other cube bikes. I did not get what you mean. Do you know that can I screw rack or carrier on Analog? I mean is there hole for installing screw on it? I mean this http://www.orchid-co.com/Files%5CInshape/a3/a3b94860-de03-4242-b73f-adedd91977a9.jpg

Comment: You can use a unicycle as a touring bike.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I did not know what is unicycle, but now I did a little search, lol and I think you are right, but I needed to talk about my bike with people who know bikes better than me (someone like you) and make sure that is this right selection or not

Comment: @DanielRHicks - OMG it is actually a thing. That wins the internet for me today!

Comment: 40 day touring event?  Hold on, are you buying this bike to use as a mountain bike later?  If not, I gotta believe you can get a better touring bike for a lot less $$ than this.  I'd be looking at a steel frame chromoly bike, with hard forks, set up with lots of lugs everywhere, and drop bars.  (steel and hard fork for robustness and reliability.) But that's just one person's opinion.  What are your full plans for this bike?

Comment: There are basically three questions you need to answer:  1) How can you carry the gear you need, 2) will the handling/performance of the bike be suitable for long distance touring, and 3) will the bike be (reasonably) comfortable to ride over the distances involved.  The bike you reference appears to be far from ideal in at least the first two cases, but it's up to you to decide if that's a deal-breaker.

Comment: @zipzit I want to use it as my bike in town, mountain and more, I'm full time on my bike, and I don't use other transportation. and the discount that I got is really good

Comment: @DanielRHicks I want to use this as mountain bike later, and the problem is that I don't know that can I screw rack on the back of my bike or not. rack means http://www.orchid-co.com/Files%5CInshape/a3/a3b94860-de03-4242-b73f-adedd91977a9.jpg

Comment: You can always use a rack that mounts to the axle (the one you reference appears to be such a unit), but that is less than ideal.  Also keep in mind that mounting the unit may require tools and a trip to the hardware store  and/or bike shop.  The bike will not readily accept a front rack.

Comment: I believe these bikes would make more sense... for a 40 day trip or city use.  Buy the bike, use it for the trip, sell it then buy the mountain bike.  `http://www.cube.eu/produkte/hardtail/`  (hit the all models button on the right hand side of the screen)  That travel exc would be perfect (in fact I suspect that is the same frame as the bike you are looking at, and shows the rear rack mounted to the lugs that are barely visible in your photo.)

Comment: @zipzit - switching to drop bars means you'd also need new levers, and the levers probably won't be compatible with the existing brakes and derailleurs, so you'd need to replace those too. At that point, you might as well just buy a different bike.

Comment: I rode for three months with people who had whatever bike they happened to own before the trip, some which were picked up on hard rubbish day. One person rode the last month with no ball bearings in their bottom bracket. Pretty much anything *can* be done.

Comment: The most important thing I'd replace on that bike before a tour is the tires. Schwalbe Smart Sams (the less expensive version) is NOT VERY PUNCTURE RESISTANT. I'd get Schwalbe Marathon Mondial, or any tire with good puncture resistance. You don't want to be patching tubes every day on a tour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Didn't look at the 2015 model (just your link - 2016 model).  On the rear there are rack bosses that can be used to mount a conventional rear rack. The rear brake is also on the lower stay which will keep it out of the way when mounting a rack (good news). There are however no such bosses on a suspension fork so you will need a more specialized rack (e.g., [old man mountain](http://www.oldmanmountain.com/Pages/RackPages/FrontRacks.html)) that uses clamps in place of bosses, if you want a front rack.

Once you have racks installed you will need to also purchase panniers (bags that securely mount to racks).  Or if you are especially creative you may find other ways to to secure regular bags (don't underestimate the difficulty, panniers will generally work much better).

As for fenders, this will depend on the fenders(full, partial, metal, plastic, etc) and tires you want to use, your final clearances and your ingenuity as you don't have any dedicated fender eyelets left once you mount the rear rack.  If you don't have a lot of experience coming up with solutions for fitting fenders you may need to seek help.

---

### Alternate Answer

*As a completely alternate answer that indirectly address your original question...*

you may also want to consider frame bags.  These require no racks and mount directly to the frame, handle bars and seat post.

There are lots of tutorials available on the internet, here is one from [Adventure Cyclist](http://www.adventurecycling.org/adventure-cyclist/online-features/ultralight-touring/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I get almost everything, but can you please answer these questions shortly? (I need it)   1) Can I use it as a touring bike (for about 40 days)?      2) Should I change tires?

Comment: @Kermani -   1) If the bike fits well, and you sort out your racks and panniers I can't see any reason you couldn't ride it for 40 days. 2) what type of terrain are you riding? - if it is mostly road you will likely want more touring-specific tires - they will roll better on pavement, last through 40 days of riding and provide puncture protection.

Comment: The problem that I have is I don't know that can I install racks on the back or not, and I don't know how can I understand, I don't have much time, the Cube dealer that is giving me this discount just has 3 of Analog, and I must select it if I need, if I can't use this I must buy a Chinese bike because I don't have enough money. I need to screw racks on the back!

Comment: As I said in the answer there appears to be bosses (threaded holes in the frames for mounting things) for mounting a rear rack.  Not all rear racks however mount in this fashion, some models attach to the rear axle or seat tube for bikes without dedicated bosses.

Comment: Yes touring tires.  Yes you can mount a rack. It is an aluminum bike and will not take as much weight as a steel bike.

Comment: Last resort is to use a bum bag or a smaller backpack, but its the worst option.  If you have some cash, consider a bike trailer.  Round here they can be bought for about the same cost as a full set of panniers and racks etc.  Plus it leaves your bike unencumbered should you want to store the gear at a campsite and go on a day excursion.

Answer (score 4):

Along with to what has already been said, the bike is less than ideal, but you now have purchased it and it can be used, probably quite successfully. For a 40 day tour with that bike I would consider replacing the front fork and/or bars with a touring fork and butterfly bars - although your budget, biking experience and tolerance for less than perfect fit may mean you wish to leave it as is.

The new fork solves the front rack mounting problem and removes the suspension (a disadvantage when touring) and will reduce weight. Swapping the fork and keeping the same bars is an easy 30 minute job. You would need a fork with the correct steerer (looks like a straight 1/18th) and would need the correct axle to steerer length so as not to throw out the bikes geometry. it would also need disk mounts and the same axle as your wheel (or a new wheel). Steel would be my material of choice.

Butterfly bars gives you more hand positions choices than a flat bar, and come in sizes that allows you to keep the MTB shifters and brake levers. Swapping bars is a bit more work, but still reasonably straight forward. I would also consider throwing on an adjustable stem to allow simple bar height adjustment.

An easier (and cheaper) alternate to swapping to butterfly bars would be bar end extensions and maybe an aerobar of some sort. Personally I do not like extension on a MTB due to increased risk of injury in a crash, but for touring, they provide another hand position. Again, an adjustable stem could be a worth while investment.